# Test resource files with Go

Tags: go, testing, directory-structure

I'm a java developer and I'm using Maven for most of my projects. The structure is quite simple:

```
  - src
    - main
      - java
      - resources
    - test
      - java
      - resources
```

Normally, for tests, I'm using the test/resources folder for files like JSON, SQL or anything else related to the tests.

Now, developing in Go, I see that tests are in the same package (folder) as the code. But where do you put the resources related to tests? Does anyone have tips on this?

Just that I don't really know where to put my resources related to the tests. I can put my files in the same package, but for me it's not a good segregation.

Comment: You can put them under `testfiles/` directory under the package.

Comment: @BurakSerdar so you have one folder (testfiles) that contains your resources? You do this most of the time?

Comment: I usually have `testfiles/` under every package that needs it. Tests run in the directory they are declared, so you can access those files using "./testdata/fname" from the tests.

Comment: The testfiles directory is documented at https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a special folder name for that: `testdata`.
It seems this is not well documented, as stated in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14715).

The Go compiler ignores folders named `testdata`. It is not only convention to name your folder that, it is also handled specifically in the toolchain.

As said [in the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages):

> The go tool will ignore a directory named "testdata", making it available to hold ancillary data needed by the tests.